# How to set read request timeout for cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I try to create new endpoints for cassandra with different read request timeout. The endpoint with big timeout for requests with big data responds. 
I found Scala code with com.datastax.cassandra driver and cassandra-default.yaml with read_request_timeout parameter. How to set read_request_timeout in Cluster builder or in other places in code ?

```
Cluster
      .builder
      .addContactPoints(cassandraHost.split(","): _*)
      .withPort(cassandraPort)
      .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
      .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
        new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build())).build



# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set at query level using :

```
session.execute(
        new SimpleStatement("CQL HERE").setReadTimeoutMillis(65000));
```

If you want to set while cluster bulding use :

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
        .withSocketOptions(
                new SocketOptions()
                        .setConnectTimeoutMillis(2000))
        .build();
```

[Socket Options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/socket_options/)

Comment: Thanks, there is the .setReadTimeoutMillis instead .setConnectTimeoutMillis in second part of code.